# If I delete a mySQL database on phpmyadmin will it affect the content uploaded on my ftp server?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

If I delete a mySQL database on phpmyadmin will it affect the content uploaded on my ftp server? Are mySQL tables and FTP content related somehow? I am using wordpress to set up the website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not related.

Deleting a MySQL database will not impact FTP.

Comment: unless the mysql db files are in the ftp area, of course... weird, but possible.

Comment: @MarcB: Well, no.  Even if you delete the database that would not delete any folder the database is in.  FTP would still work fine.  Of course if someone expected to download the backing files for the database via FTP, the backing files would not be there.  I'm pretty sure that's not the scenario here.

Comment: I mean the .frm/myd/myi/ib_* files. but that's why I said weird, but possible.

Answer (score 1):

No. The deletion will not affect the files on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Databases have no direct relationship to your FTP files so deleting the database will not delete the FTP content. There is a possibility that your website is using the data in your database to reference the FTP content though. I don't know what you website does but if you give the ability to upload files these may be stored in your FTP directory with a file listing from the database. Therefore deleting the database may break your website and you would no longer have the data that is stored in your database regarding your FTP files. Let me know if you have any questions regarding this.